# Estimating VAR using statistical softwares.

Tags: statistics, var

Assuming all my data are stationary or integrated of the same order, does it matter if I estimate the equations individually or estimate them together as a VAR?

p.s. I am using Stata, an econometrics package, which allows me to estimate all at the same time.

Thanks!

Comment: You might wish to try this question on [stats.se]

Answer (score 0):

If you are most interested in the parameter estimates, it will not matter if you estimate individual equations. For the sake of equation estimation, the VAR framework is not a really a "system", but simply a juxtaposition of related models.

The purpose of the VAR framework is to analyze the "ripple effects" that shocks to one or more endogenous variables can have. If you estimate your equations individually, it will be difficult to replicate VAR features like impulse-response plots.

I encourage you to try estimating a simple set of equations both within the VAR framework and individually. You will see that the parameter estimates are identical.